# Javascript callback() for two functions

Tags: javascript, callback

I have two questions regarding the callback on JavaScript.

First: Does the `for` loop run asynchronously? That is, in the function:

```
function postData(items, callback)
{
   for(var i=0 ; i < items.length ; i++)
   {
      //angularjs Post request
      $http.post("http://www....", item[i]);
   }

   callback();
}
```

Will the `callback()` wait until the cycle is finished?

Second: How can I wait for a callback of two functions?

I have another function `deleteData(items, callback)` that I want to run async with the `postData()`. When the two are done I want to do some "refresh".

For now I'm using:

```
function postData(items, callback)
{
  for(var i=0 ; i < items.length ; i++)
   {
      //angularjs Post request
      $http.post("http://www....", item[i]);
   }

   callback();
}

function deleteData(items, callback)
{
  for(var i=0 ; i < items.length ; i++)
   {
      //angularjs delete request
      $http.delete("http://www....", item[i].id);
   }

   callback();
}

function refresh()
{
  $http.get("www....").success....
}

function doit(post, delete)
{
   postData(post, function(){
      deleteData(delete, function(){
          refresh();
      })
   });
}
```

Is it possible to make `postData` and `deleteData` run assync and when the both are done run the `refresh`?

----- EDIT -----

To make sure that the callback is send after the cycle is done, I use the code like this:

```
function postData(items, callback)
{
  if(items.length == 0)
    callback();
  for(var i=0 ; i < items.length ; i++)
   {
      //angularjs Post request
      $http.post("http://www....", item[i]);

      if(i == items.length-1)
         callback();
   }

   callback();
}
```

But it looks ugly... I was hoping for a cleaner solution...

replying to Ivan, Angular has also callback for the http requests, I don't need to use $ajax and I don't want to callback for each http request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the $q promise library, you can achieve that.
If you are using angular, $q is already in your project, just include it in the service/controller you are using.

[$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) does exactly what you are looking for.

**Example of how it would look:**

```
var promises = [];

// loop x times
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i ++){
    var promise = $http.post("http://www....", item[i]);
    promises.push(promise);
}

// Refresh will be called when all posts are completed.
$q.all(promises).then(refresh);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need... And thank you for the updated answer with the example

Answer (score -1):

First: no, it will not wait.

Second: Use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) :

```
function postData(items, callback)
{
  for(var i=0 ; i < items.length ; i++)
   {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://www....",
        ...........
      }).done(function() {
        callback();
      });
   }
}
```

Or alternatively vanilla JS:

```
function postData(items, callback)
{
  for(var i=0 ; i < items.length ; i++)
   {
      var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
      r.open("POST", "http://www....", true);
      r.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return; 
        callback();
      };
   }
}
```

Comment: The OP does not use jQuery.

Comment: @Tomalak, sorry, but what is OP?

Comment: "Original Poster" - The person who started the thread. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op&defid=2172424

Comment: @Tomalak, Thanks for clarifying. I've changed the answer according to your comment

Comment: According to your answer it will send a callback for each post request... that's not what I want. I want a callback when all post request are done...